# Find domain of the quotient of two square root functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, radicals, fractions

**Question**:
Given
$$f(x)=\sqrt{36-x^2} \\
g(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$$
then find
$$\left(\frac fg\right)(x) = \sqrt{\frac{36-x^2}{x+1}}$$
and find its domain.

**My Solution**:
The domain comes from
$$x+1\ne0$$
and (intersection)
$$\frac{36-x^2}{x+1}\ge0.$$
The first part implies that
$x\ne-1$. But
$$\frac{36-x^2}{x+1} \ge 0$$
when $x$ is in $(-\infty,-6] \cup (-1,6].$

So **my final answer** is $(-\infty,-6] \cup (-1,6]$.

**WebAssign's Answer**: $(-1,6]$.

Comment: *Given* $f(x) = \sqrt{36-x^2}$ means that $x^2 \le 36$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the new function is a quotient of two functions, the domains of the original functions need to be taken into account too. In this case $f(x)$ has domain $[-6,6]$ and $g(x)$ has domain $[-1,\infty)$, so these needs to be intersected with the calculated domain $(-\infty,-6]\cup(-1,6]$ to get the correct answer of $(-1,6]$.

Comment: Are you suggesting that if the question had just been find the domain of F(x)="same formula as (f/g) above" my solution would have been correct?

Comment: @Jeff Yes.${}{}$

Comment: Is it correct to say, intuitively, that the domain of $(f/g)(x)$ is the intersection of $f$'s domain, $g$'s domain and $(f+g)$'s domain?

Comment: @Jeff Where $f$ is defined, $g$ is defined and $g$ is not zero. Then yes, the domain of $f/g$ is the intersection of those domains.

Answer (score 2):

The domain of $\frac{f}{g}$ is $x+1>0$ and $36-x^2\geq0,$ which is

$x>-1$ and $-6\leq x\leq6$ or

$-1<x\leq6,$ which gives the answer: $(-1,6]$.